# How to Save UITableViewController cells after rearrange to NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I've an iOS application developed using Objective-C & Xcode 6.4

Right know I'm working on manually rearranging the UITableViewController cells, everything working great. But after I press the bar button EDIT and the "3 underlines" appear to drag the cell anywhere I want in the UITableViewController, ***(( I can't save what I did ))***. So **how could I do a Persistent save the changes done to the table cells location ??** I mean, How to save The new rearranged `NSMutableArray` to a Property list -`NSUserDefaults`-.

I'm using a Mutable Array to display the table's cells and these methods below:

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    FileWML *fileWML = [self.filesWML objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [self.filesWML removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [self.filesWML insertObject:fileWML atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
}
```

**PLUS** would someone tell me **how I can make the edit button display the word Done, while editing ?**

***(( I can't save what I did ))*** *means: after I do the rearranging order I want, and then I go to the home view then I get back to the table view I edit and rearrange, the rearranging order I did get back to the default order. So, all the rearranging I did is gone.*

*Thanks and every help is appreciated.*

Comment: Try [tableView visibleCells ]. It will give you all cells which are on the screen.

Comment: What do you mean by 'can't save'? do you mean when you move location of cells they do not remain at there new positions after scrolling or reloading table View?

Comment: What do you mean by 'can't save'? I mean after I close my app or go to a different view controller. And then I get back, the rearranging order I did get back to the way it was before I edit it. (is it clear like this ??)

Comment: From where you are fetching your table view data?

Comment: From separate file contain the array data, and I already import the file to my header.

Comment: Save as in Persistant save or untill app is in memory save?

Answer (score 2):

You have to load your datas from your file in an array. This array will be your tableView dataSource.
When a row is moved, in the delegate method you have to change the object's place in the array. Your array should always be the same as your tableview !
Once the editing of the tableview is done you save the array in the file. The previous content in file should be erased. Then you reload your datas ([tableView reloadData].

Comment: all of that will be done in the `moveRowAtIndexPath` method. right ? 1- change the object's place in the array. 2- Your array should always be the same as your tableview. 3- Once the editing of the tableview is done you save the array in the file. 4- The previous content in file should be erased. Would you please be kind enough and provide the codes for it. And thanks either way :)

Comment: Not sure, I think I'll try in tableView: didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: and the codes ? can you provide them ?? I already start looking for them but it will be better if you can write them for me.

Comment: I'm on my iPhone but you have to get object from your array at its original index, then delete the original row in your array, insert the object at its new index. Then call the reloadData on your tableView to see modifications on the screen.

Comment: In `moveRowAtIndexPath` method, I added these lines: `FileWML *fileWML = [self.filesWML objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [self.filesWML removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [self.filesWML insertObject:fileWML atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
    
    [tableView reloadData];
}`    Still didn't work, the rearranged order I set was gone after I went to home view. any new idea ??